# Compare values of each records in field 1 to find min and max values AWK

Tags: bash, csv, awk, text-processing, gawk

I am new to text preprocessing and AWK language.

I am trying to loop through each record in a given field(field1) and find the max and min of values and store it in a variable.

Algorithm :

1) Set Min = 0 and Max = 0

2) Loop through $1(field 1)

3) Compare FNR of the field 1 and set Max and Min

4) Finally print Max and Min

this is what I tried :

```
BEGIN{max = 0; min = 0; NF = 58}
{
     for(i = 0; i < NF-57; i++)
     {

           for(j =0; j < NR; j++)
           {
             min = (min < $j) ? min : $j
             max = (max > $j) ? max : $j
           }
     }
}
END{print max, min}

#Dataset
f1  f2  f3  f4 .... f58
0.3 3.3 0.5 3.6
0.9 4.7 2.5 1.6 
0.2 2.7 6.3 9.3
0.5 3.6 0.9 2.7
0.7 1.6 8.9 4.7
```

Here, f1,f2,..,f58 are the fields or columns in Dataset.

I need to loop through column one(f1) and find Min-Max.

Output Required:
Min = 0.2
Max = 0.9

What I get as a result:
Min = ''(I dont get any result)
Max = 9.3(I get max of all the fields instead of field1)

**This is for learning purpose so I asked for one column So that I can try on my own for multiple columns**

These is what I have:

This for loop would only loop 4 times as there r only four fields. Will the code inside the for loop execute for each record that is, for 5 times?

```
for(i = 0; i < NF; i++)
{
    if (min[i]=="") min[i]=$i
    if (max[i]=="") max[i]=$i
    if ($i<min[i]) min[i]=$i
    if ($i>max[i]) max[i]=$i
}

END
{
    OFS="\t"; 
    print "min","max";
    #If I am not wrong, I saved the data in an array and I guess this would be the right way to print all min and max?
    for(i=0; i < NF; i++;)
    {
            print min[i], max[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Some input data to this would be pretty much essential to see too.

Comment: in your example, the minimum value of the first column is `0.2` and not `0.3`, please define what should be your minimum

Comment: Is the `f1`, `f2` etc. part of the actual input, or did you just add that as an annotation for us?

Comment: Yes, I just added for explanation(annotation) but they dont exist.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia - just to clarify: you want the global min and max (i.e. across all lines) *just* for field 1, correct?

Comment: @Smeeheey Yes, only in field 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working solution which is really much easier than what you are doing:

`/^-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$/` checks that `$1` is indeed a valid number, otherwise it is discarded.

```
sort -n | awk '$1 ~ /^-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$/ {a[c++]=$1} END {OFS="\t"; print "min","max";print a[0],a[c-1]}'
```

If you don't use this, then min and max need to be initialized, for example with the first value:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$/ {if (min=="") min=$1; if (max=="") max=$1; if ($1<min) min=$1; if ($1>max) max=$1} END {OFS="\t"; print "min","max";print min, max}'
```

Readable versions:

```
sort -n | awk '
$1 ~ /^-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$/ {
  a[c++]=$1
}
END {
  OFS="\t"
  print "min","max"
  print a[0],a[c-1]
}'
```

and

```
awk '
  $1 ~ /^-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$/ {
    if (min=="") min=$1
    if (max=="") max=$1
    if ($1<min) min=$1
    if ($1>max) max=$1
  }
  END {
    OFS="\t"
    print "min","max"
    print min, max
  }'
```

On your input, is outputs:

```
min     max
0.2     0.9
```

**EDIT (replying to the comment requiring more information on how `awk` works)**:

Awk loops through `lines` (named `records`) and for each line you have columns (named `fields`) available. Each `awk` iteration reads a line and provides among others the `NR` and `NF` variables. In your case, you are only interested in the first column, so you will only use `$1` which is the first column `field`. For each `record` where `$1` is matching `/^-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$/` which is a regex matching positive and negative integers or floats, we are either storing the value in an array `a` (in the first version) or setting the `min`/`max` variables if needed (in the second version).

Here is the explanation for the condition `$1 ~ /^-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$/`:

- `$1 ~` means we are checking if the first field `$1` matches the regex between slashes
- `^` means we start matching from the beginning of the `$1` field
- `-?` means an optional `minus sign`
- `[0-9]*` is any number of digits (including zero, so `.1` or `-.1` can be matched)
- `()?` means an optional block which can be present or not
- `\.[0-9]*` if that optional block is present, it should start with a `dot` and contain zero or more digits (so `-.` or `.` can be matched! adapt the regex if you have uncertain input)
- `$` means we are matching until the last character from the `$1` field

If you wanted to loop through `fields`, you would have to use a for loop from `1` to `NF` (included) like this:

```
echo "1 2 3 4" | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if (min=="") min=$(i); if (max=="") max=$(i); if ($(i)<min) min=$(i); if ($(i)>max) max=$(i)}} END {OFS="\t"; print "min","max";print min, max}'
```

(please note that I have not checked the input here for simplicity purposes)

Which outputs:

```
min     max
1       4
```

If you had more lines as an input, `awk` would also process them after reading the first `record`, example with this input:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

Outputs:

```
min     max
1       8
```

To prevent this and only work on the first line, you can add a condition like `NR == 1` to process only the first line or add an `exit` statement after the `for` loop to stop processing the input after the first line.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but Can you please explain the regex code"$1 ~ /^-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$/ " ? Also, could you explain how does AWK work in terms of columns and rows? Like I dont understand if I need to loop through records in a field how to do it in awk style Or how to loop though fields in awk style. I dont mind if you share a link that explain AWK's basic principle

Comment: I hope the pieces of information I added will satisfy your curiosity :)

Comment: I added detailed regex explanation.

Comment: I saw the explaination and I understood the working of it. I am trying to push the solution for multiple columns now on my own. And I have modified your piece of code to work for multiple cols too. I will updated the code below, please have a look at it.

Comment: Please check my code for multiple columns, what you think of it, I have commented the bits I dont understand

Comment: This should be asked in a separate question... I don't know where I should  correct your code... you are doing lots of syntax errors in your new code. missing `{}` around the `for` loop, `i` ranging from `0..NF-1` instead of `1..NF`, extra `;`, extra newline, unclear requirement, ... In any case, here is a fixed version: http://sprunge.us/aAdL (instead of `./temp < temp2`, I could have used other calling methods, like `awk -f temp < temp2` or `./temp temp2`...)

Comment: I got it working for all the columns, check my new post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883643/awk-how-records-and-fields-are-executed-and-read?noredirect=1#comment63222093_37883643

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to only column 1, you may try this:

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]].*/{if($1<min||!min){min=$1};if($1>max){max=$1}}END{print min,max}' dataset
```

The script looks for line starting with digit and set the min or max if it didn't find it before.

Comment: The task is to find min and max of all the fields. As you can see, the expected max is 9.3 and is located in the fourth column

Comment: @GMichael it's not what i read from the text: _Output Required: Min = 0.2 Max = 0.9_

Comment: This works, good job. Just remove the useless `cat` because awk can do the job just fine (^^)

Comment: Very nice usage of `|!min`, I'll be sure to use it in the future. Of course, if the input may contain only negative numbers, you'd have to add `|!max` as well :)